# Getting a sum for every distinct value in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of Fantasy Football Managers and 15 players on each of their teams. I can do the following to list all the teams with "Robin Van Persie" in it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `players` 
WHERE MATCH(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15) 
AGAINST ('Robin Van Persie' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and I can do this to count how many have "Robin Van Persie" in it (returns just a number).

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `players` 
WHERE MATCH(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15) 
AGAINST ('Robin Van Persie' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But is there a way for me to get a list similar to this?

```
Count | Player Name
-------------------------
62    | Robin Van Persie
12    | Wayne Rooney
22    | Michu
31    | Theo Walcott
```

For each distinct value in the database?

Comment: You should first normalize your database so that all players have their own row instead of a column.

Comment: I've never done normalization, but in this database, the order is important. For example, the p1-p11 are the actual team and p12-p15 are subs. Will normalization mess that up? If it helps, I have a separate database with all separate Player Names.

Comment: Then for each player add their index as well.

Comment: Consider which information is important to keep track of for each player.  Your Table could have Player_ID, Name, Position, etc. Whether they are actual team or subs would be in a field, with values 'actual' or 'sub' or some such.  Any data can be normalized without losing detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to have three tables.

**table 1**
In the "players" table, you have 2 columns: the primary id, and the list of all the players.

**table 2**
The "managers" table also has 2 columns: each manager name, and a primary Id.

**table 3**
The "managers_players" table associates the primary ID of each manager with the primary id of each player on her or his team.  So technically, this table has 3 columns: the table primary id, the managers id, and the players id.  So this table will have multiple instances of both the same manager id and also the same player id.

With this structure, you can run a query like this (might need to use "binarys" on the inner joins):

```
SELECT m.name, count(mp.player_id) as count
FROM managers_players mp
inner join managers m
on  mp.manager_id =  m.id
inner join players p
on p.id = mp.player_id
group by m.id
order by count DESC;
```

This schema would also make it really easy to see the players on each managers team:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM managers_players mp
inner join managers m
on m.id = mp.manager_id
inner join players p
on p.id = mp.player id
where m.name like '%Manager Name%';
```

or do `select m.name` and change the where clause to `p.name` to see all the managers who have a particular player.

Comment: Sounds a bit more complicated than I expected... I do already have table 1 and table 2 set up. My third table is as you see in the top of this post with 15 columns for players.

Comment: I could run something simple which does my query above and loop it for every player name in my database, but that'd take a lot longer to run. I'll take a look at your suggestion to see if it's worth my while changing as it'll take me a while to do and then re-get the info again. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, that would take longer to run, but the net time lost might still be faster than implementing my suggestions: http://www.xkcd.com/1205/ You could try experimenting with nested conditions or select statements.  If it's just a small thing with your friends, I'd just find a "good enough" hack and wouldn't take the time to fix the schema, but if this is for a production platform, I'd definitely suggest abstracting it more in line with the schema I suggested.